# How to read huge file and write on a file in java using Horizontal or Vertical Scaling

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently i was asked in an interview , how to read huge file (single file of 1TB) in java.I said by using Threading , we will create two File objects and one thread will read it from the beginning and other Thread will read from last. May be this is Stupid answer.And the Interviewer gave hint , by using Horizontal/Vertical Scaling , Clustering.
I have seen in Google there is no Example for Horizontal/Vertical Scaling , Clustering and reading files.can anyone help

Comment: Your question is way too broad; and in the end; answers would be opinion based; as there simply many different but valid ways to attack such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This interview question is quite open; it tries to have you talk and think out loud. There will be many answers.

My personal interpretation:

Both scaling do not refer to classes or frameworks. They are concepts in architectures. Start with wikipedia if you are not clear on that.

Vertical scaling: here they probably want you to see how you can improve performance on a single host to get this huge file job done. This involves better disks, raid, multithreading of course. If any CPU/memory is heavily loaded, perhaps having more cpu and memory.

Horizontal scaling: this is usually about how to divide the problem across multiple jvm hosts to have the file processed concurrently, in a divide and conquer, scatter/gather pattern.